# MySQL connector net 6.9.9 setup wizard ended prematurely

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've been running into a couple of issues trying to use the entity framework in visual studio with an MySql database.
I Figured I'd just try and reinstall the MySQL Connector net, I uninstalled using control panel but when I try to reinstall it it rolles back and just says it ended prematurely and to retry later, I've retried a couple of times, rebooted, tried older versions but nothing seems to work.

When I check windows logs it says: Status van geslaagde/mislukte installatie: 1603.
Whuch doesn't really tell me much more, even after a google search.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I've also tried software to completely remove every last trace of MySql connector net but without any success.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLRBf.png)

Thanks

Comment: Well if it tells you nothing, what is it going to tell us as we are not there looking over your shoulder and we are not clairvoyant

Comment: If I knew what caused it I'd be able to put it here, unfortunately I don't so I thought maybe someone could help me trouble shoot it or at least ask for certain additional information that could aid me into finding the issue...

Comment: That's a very generic error. I would try to completely delete the installation folder and even look for any references in the registry. Also make sure you`ve got latests .net framework installed

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after hours and hours of searching I gave up and just decided to install it on my laptop and go from there. During installation a noticed the installer was consulting the machine.config file.

During an issue I had earlier the solution was to eddit this file and comment some stuff out. removed these comments and add everything back and installed again and now it worked.

Hours wasted again for nothing.

Thanks everyone for your help and searching.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning you didn't have an untouched machine.config. It made me remember I had made some changes to it previously. After I restored my original machine.config I was able to install My Sql connector (6.9.9)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to uninstall MySQL Connector/NET v6.6.4. The answer provided by @Ben was not applicable to me; I had no reference to mysql in any machine.config files...

After lots of different attempts, I finally got there. In the end, I re-tried to remove the program from control panel (which showed me where the installation msi file had originally been lumped *(C:\Windows\installer\43acc6b.msi in my case)*.

With this original msi location identified, I then opened up a command prompt (as admin), and keyed in:

```
msiexec /x "C:\Windows\installer\43acc6b.msi" /L*V "C:\temp\mylog.log"
```

This instructs an msi uninstallation, with verbose logs to the specified location.

In my case I eventually found a stack trace, which complained that it couldn't find part of the path on C:\Extensions\extensions.configurationchanged. As I didn't even have a C:\Extensions folder, I created one and re-ran the command. Bingo :)

Hope that helps someone